# Use promise to call another function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call a second function after a first function is complete with an ajax call. I was doing this previously by calling the second function in the success portion of the first function like so

```
function1(){
    $.ajax({
       success: function(results)
            function2(results);
    })
}
```

I am trying to make this more elegant and not tie these functions together. I just started experimenting with [$.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

I am trying to write code that would look something like this

```
function1().promise().done(function(results){
    function2(results);
});

function1({
   $.ajax({
       success: function(results){
            return results;
       }
   })
})
```

I could be going about this the completely wrong way. Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Just an FYI: You can't use a `return` from inside the `success` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **return** the promise that is returned by `$.ajax`:

```
function1() {
   return $.ajax({...});
}

function1().done(function2);
```

`.promise`, the function you are referring to, is a method of a *jQuery object*. But `$.ajax` doesn't return a jQuery object, it returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), which directly implements the promise interface.

See also: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) and the jQuery documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/.

Comment: Pretty sure you can do `$.ajax().promise()`, but that doesn't do anything, as `$.ajax()` is already a promise.  You only need `promise()` when doing something like `var d = new $.Deferred;`.